# Where does the iOS Simulator save screen shots?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I can't find iOS simulator screenshots (supposedly created using <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) since updating to Xcode 4.3 (running on 10.7.3 Lion).

They aren't in `~Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Screenshots`.

Presumably they moved when Xcode moved from `Developer`, but Spotlight can't tell me where they are either.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23661097/change-the-location-of-screen-shots-saved-by-the-ios-simulator for an updated answer

Answer (score 150, accepted):

iOS Simulator screen shots are saved to your desktop (`~/Desktop`).  The file names are of the form `iOS Simulator Screen shot Feb 28, 2012 12.16.23 PM.png`.

You can also choose Edit > Copy Screen (default shortcut: <kbd>⌃⌘C</kbd>) to copy the screen shot directly to your clipboard.

Comment: Crikey, 27" Thunderbolt display, and still I didn't spot them behind all those open windows ;-)  Thanks.

Comment: What a lame default. Oh wait it's not a default because it's not customizable. Double lame. Still, it's super handy to be able to save screenshots so I guess I can forgive it a bit.

Comment: @devios1, Now [you can](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46458040/865175).

Answer (score 29):

Press Command+S. The screen shot will be saved on your desktop.

Answer (score 5):

On iOS 9.3, the screen shots are called `Simulator Screen Shot <timestamp>.png` and are still located in `~/Desktop`.

Answer (score 4):

For Xamarin developers using remote MAC pairing from windows, the screenshots are located in Pictures > Xamarin > iOS Simulator directory.

Answer (score 1):

For newcomers, let's just use Xcode "Debug" option in the Menu:

### Debug -> View Debugging -> Take screenshot of yourPhoneName

(see image below)

The screenshots are saved on the Desktop. I tried only for phone connected to my computer, but it should work also on simulators.

[image]