# Can I customize where the iOS Simulator saves its screenshots to? (Instead of the Desktop)

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I'm continually frustrated by the simulator saving all my screenshots (from command+s in the simulator) to my Desktop, just flooding it after a few weeks. Can I have it save them somewhere else?

I know I could just use Grab.app or cmd+shift+4, but it the simulator crops out the top bar, shadows, etc. which is nice, so I'd like to keep it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change the Location of Screen Shots Saved by the iOS Simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23661097/change-the-location-of-screen-shots-saved-by-the-ios-simulator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Xcode 8.x & earlier**:
No.  It is always saved on the desktop.  There is no option to change that.

**Xcode 9.x**:

Select File, Save Screenshot while holding down the Option key. We will prompt you for the location to save the screenshot. Check the box to make this location the default for all screenshots going forward.