# How to Change Directory where iOS Simulator Saves Screenshots?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

When saving a screenshot from the iOS Simulator, the screenshots are saved to the Desktop

After taking a few, my Desktop is quickly polluted with screen shots that don't belong there.

How does one change the directory where iOS Simulator screenshots are saved?

In some issue related to where screenshot gets stored, a commenter responded that 'by default' they get stored on the desktop (implying it could be changed).

(iOS Simulator 8.0, Xcode 6.0.1, Mac OS X 10.9.5)

Answer (score 7):

Following on from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44810443/14868

As of **Xcode 9**, you can also set the output folder using the defaults command and integrate it with any machine setup you use.

Example:

`defaults write com.apple.iphonesimulator ScreenShotSaveLocation "$HOME/Screen Shots"`

Answer (score 4):

**Xcode 9** adds behavior for setting a custom directory for iOS Simulator screenshots.

Press <kbd>⌥⌘S</kbd> or **Hold the** <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> **key** and select the menu item:

```
File > New Screen Shot...
```

This presents a file "Save As..." dialog. Note the new checkbox on the dialog:

> Use this as the default location

Check that checkbox to change the default directory for <kbd>⌘S</kbd> iOS Simulator screenshots.

[image: Menu item for "New Screen Shot..."]

[image: Checkbox for "Use this as the default location"]

Comment: Hint: You still have to keep the option key (alt key) pressed when clicking on "New Screen Shot".

Comment: Easiest solution.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: [iOS Simulator custom screenshot directory support added in Xcode 9 beta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44810443/1265393)

The iOS Simulator does not currently have an option to change the default screenshot directory.

Please duplicate my bug report! http://bugreport.apple.com

```
rdar://26127809
Allow iOS Simulator to specify a non-Desktop directory for CMD-S screenshots.
```

In the mean time, I use the app [Hazel](http://www.noodlesoft.com/hazel.php) to automatically move iOS Simulator screenshots (taken via ⌘S) from the default Desktop location to my Simulator Screenshots folder.

> Hazel watches whatever folders you tell it to, automatically organizing your files according to the rules you create.

http://www.noodlesoft.com/hazel.php

[image: Hazel interface.]

Answer (score -2):

You will not be able to do that.

An easy alternative could be:

1. press cmd+shft+4
2. press spacebar
3. Click your iPad/iPhone simulator window

with changing the default screenshot directory:
[Change the Screen Shot Save File Location in Mac OS X](http://osxdaily.com/2011/01/26/change-the-screenshot-save-file-location-in-mac-os-x/)

Comment: It's bad if you want the native resolution of the simulator screen.